# Mobile SharePoint - opening PDF

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint and need to create a mobile SharePoint site. How can we have a document list/library listing all PDF files on mobile? Is it possible to view PDF file using mobile SharePoint 2010?